# plot.new error in R markdown

Tags: r, plot, knitr, r-markdown

I have some R code to plot an ellipse for a bivariate normal with known mean and variance using the `ellipse()` function from the `mixtools` package. However when I run this in Rmarkdown I get an error saying "plot.new has not been called yet". When I put another plot directly above it in the same chunk it runs but otherwise I get the error. What's the reason for this?

```
plot(ellipse(params,covariance, npoints = 500, alpha=0.01),
 xlim = c(-2,3.5),
 ylim = c(0,.75), xlab="alpha", ylab = "beta")
```

This code works fine when just run in `R`, the issue is only in markdown.

Comment: are you sure it's from calibrate? https://github.com/cran/calibrate/blob/master/NAMESPACE

Comment: Sorry, no, mixtools

Comment: looks like you need to add `newplot = TRUE` to initialize a new plot otherwise it will use lines assuming you want to add to an existing plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mixtools` function `ellipse()` offers a plot argument, look at the [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mixtools/mixtools.pdf). So you can plot your ellipse like this:

```
ellipse(params, covariance, 
        npoints = 500, alpha=0.01, 
        newplot = TRUE, draw = TRUE, 
        xlim = c(-2,3.5), ylim = c(0,.75), 
        xlab="alpha", ylab = "beta")
```

The important arguments are `newplot = TRUE` and `draw = TRUE`. They offer you the plot of the ellipse and all other graphical parameters can be submitted to the function `ellipse()` via the three dot argument. If `newplot = TRUE` and `draw = TRUE`, plot the ellipse on a new plot. If `newplot = FALSE` and `draw = TRUE`, add the ellipse to an existing plot.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I wanted, didn't realise it had a plot argument. Thanks